# I can't seem to open an .xls format file from Salesforce printable view in Mac Numbers

Tags: reporting

Is there a way to view the "printable view" (.xls) in Mac Numbers (version 2.3+) rather than Excel? I am using OS X (Maverick), Numbers (V3.0) and both Safari and Firefox.  When I save a Salesforce report using the "printable view" button, it saves it as an .xls file but when I open it in Numbers I get what looks like the XML code behind it, for example the first cell in the first three rows contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Numbers, but the .xls file that Salesforce generates is, in fact, an HTML file, formatted in a way that Excel will open and interpret it correctly. It uses the .xls extension so that OSes that use filename extensions as their sole means of program association with file types, like Windows, will have the file associated with the 'correct' program. If Numbers is capable of opening and interpreting HTML tables, you might be able to have some success renaming the file to .html or otherwise helping Numbers to expect an HTML rather than native Excel format file.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to download the .csv version, rather than the printable view to open in Numbers. As Thomas astutely pointed out, the .xls files you download from salesforce are bold faced little white lies.

Comment: LibreOffice Calc opens the Salesforce-generated .xls documents correctly, and could be used as a go-between.